# Unexpected value 'resources'" in YAML template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

Is there a way ot declare resources in Yaml template ?

```yaml
#yaml template
parameters:
- name: p1
resources: 
   repositories: #repository with cd template
     - repository: yaml.templates
```

Comment: Much appreciate this solution shared here! You can accept your answer, so that others could directly know this is work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resources cannot currently be declared in templates.
Only the “root” yaml file may declare resources.
The current workaround is to lift all referenced resources from the template into the “root” yaml file.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/728151/unexpected-value-resources-in-yaml-template.html

Answer (score 2):

Following beatcracker in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/49

It should be possible to include resources from templates, if you utilize the extends keyword. I have not been able to confirm it since the extends keyword is currently only supported in Azure DevOps Services.

But he gave the example seen below.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: node_latest
    image: node:latest

extends:
  template: template.yml
```

template.yml

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: node_lts
    image: node:lts
```